# Rails N+1 query when using exists? on an ActiveRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model such that:

```
class Event
    has_many :participations
    has_many :participants, :through => :participations, :source => user

    def attending?(user)
        participants.exists?(user)
    end
end
```

I've noticed an N+1 query problem when I used it, such as:

```
@events = Event.all
@events.each_with_index do |event, i|
    if (event.attending?(current_user))
        ...
    end
end
```

I thought I could solve this by using includes:

```
@events = Event.includes(:participants)
```

This does not solve the N+1 query problem.  I'm not great with Ruby (this is a side project), but when debugging the code for `ActiveRecord.FinderMethods.exists?`, I believe it's always constructing a new relationship & executing this against the server, no matter what has been included.

Is my interpretation of `exists?` correct?  If not, how can I include the correct stuff to make `exists?` not exhibit an N+1 query issue?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I ended up solving this via a blend of:

```
@events = Event.includes(:participants)
```

and

```
def attending?(user)
    participants.where('user_id = ?', user.id)
end
```

Comment: are you sure this is not making a db query on each event's participant when you call the method `attending?`. I would expect it to , as you are chaining a `where` clause. I would just use `participants.include?(user)`